# Selenium using too much memory

Tags: java, python-3.x, selenium, memory-management

I'm using selenium on python 3.5 with chrome webdriver on a ububtu vps, and when I run a very basic script (navigate to site, enter login fields, click), memory usage goes up by ~400mb,and cpu usage goes up to 100%. Are there any things I can do to lower this, or if not, are there any alternatives?

I'm testing out selenium in python but I plan to do a project with it in java, where memory usage is a critical factor for me, so the same question applies for java as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget `drive.close()` in your code , if you don't close your driver, you will have a lot instance of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your memory usage problem is caused by selenium. AFAIK it runs on webkit, which is also used by Googles Chrome browser. And chrome is well known for it's excessive memory usage.

This might help:
[Selenium github issue #4988](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4988)

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen I believe unless there is a leak.
Please try install nmon on your machine and run the test.
[Nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php)

This would help in figuring out exact cause of high CPU utilization and resolve your issue.